# Cannot change decimal separator Ext.ux.grid.FiltersFeature to comma

Tags: extjs, datagrid, extjs4

I'm using ExtJS 4.1 and trying to change the decimal separator in a [numeric grid filter](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.ux.grid.filter.NumericFilter) to comma.

Here my grid filter config:

```
features: [{
    ftype: 'filters',
    encode: true,
    filters: [{
        type: 'numeric',
        dataIndex: 'frequency',
        decimalSeparator: ','
    }]
}]
```

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would override [Ext.ux.grid.menu.RangeMenu](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/extjs-build/examples/ux/grid/menu/RangeMenu.js) and add the decimalSeparator property to the default menu item configs:

```
Ext.override(Ext.ux.grid.menu.RangeMenu, {
    menuItemCfgs : {
        emptyText: 'Enter Number...',
        selectOnFocus: false,
        width: 155,
        decimalSeparator:','
    }
});
```